# Android studio fails to load terminal

Tags: android

I am using Android studio on windows 7. Recently for no apparent reason my terminal stopped loading. I googled for it but couldn't find any solution. The event log says-

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\libpty\win\x86\winpty.dll': Native library (win32-x86/C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\libpty\win\x86\winpty.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\extensions.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\jdom.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\log4j.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\trove4j.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\jna.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\lib\tools.jar)

and it looks like this. [image: this]
help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: Go to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal. And see if Shell path is correct, for me this is "cmd.exe".

Comment: I checked it and set the path to windows>system32>cmd.exe. Still not working. thanks anyway

Comment: Just set it to "cmd.exe" for me android studio dont need to go by windows/system32. If it doesnt work i dont know where it come from.

Comment: it was already cmd.exe when the problem occurred, than i did set it by the windows/system32 path. seems some of my files may have got corrupted during update or something. its so weird, like i am the only person having this problem. sigh!!

Comment: Oh ok, sorry i can't help you then, last solution : Uninstall and Reinstall. Good Luck !

Comment: hahah not doing that. keeping it for now. happy coding :)